# Node C++ extension loading in docker only Segfault on Google Compute Engine

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, docker, google-compute-engine

I am experiencing an extremely weird behavior with docker containers + node on Google Compute Engine.
The setup is the following:

1. I have a docker image pushed to a private docker registry
2. This image is created on top of ubuntu 12.04 (FROM ubuntu:12.04)
3. The code i am running is javascript Node code with a C++ extension.
4. The C++ extension contains custom C++ code as well as dynamically linked libraries (boost, blas, armadillo, etc...)

I tried running the docker container with the node code + extension on many different machines (local, and different instance sizes on AWS).

It segfaults when i launch the exact same container on GCE. It crashes on different machines and different OSs.

This is the output i get when using this [tool](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler) (I run the command from inside the container):

```
/opt/th/api# node start.js 
PID 118 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x7f1c7faab000
/opt/th/api/node-segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault_handler.node(+0x100d)  [0x7f1c8b2fa00d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f1c8b8cbcb0]
/usr/lib/libblas.so(+0x3d6fd8)[0x7f1c89229fd8]
/usr/lib/libblas.so(blas_memory_alloc+0x34d)[0x7f1c8922a70d]
/usr/lib/libblas.so(gotoblas_init+0x30)[0x7f1c88efb120]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xf306)[0x7f1c8c70a306]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xf3df)[0x7f1c8c70a3df]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x13ada)[0x7f1c8c70eada]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xf176)[0x7f1c8c70a176]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x1331a)[0x7f1c8c70e31a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0xf26)[0x7f1c8c4f7f26]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xf176)[0x7f1c8c70a176]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0x152f)[0x7f1c8c4f852f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x31)[0x7f1c8c4f7fc1]
node(uv_dlopen+0x30)[0x966000]
node(_ZN4node6DLOpenERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0xee)[0x818bfe]
node[0x5c7c0b]
[0xf956706362]
```

Has anyone seen anything like this?
It looks like a dynamic linking problem. But why would I only see this on GCE and nowhere else?

Comment: I was wondering whether it can somehow be related to GCE disks. I checked the permissions of all dynamically loaded libs and it all seems rather consistent. Inside the docker container the user is root, so it has access to all *.so files. Example: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  135366 Sep 30  2013 libpthread-2.15.so

Comment: Good to hear that you've solved your problem! Please move your "Update" section into its own answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question can be closed as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

After long hours of fighting with this problem, I found a solution by rebuilding the container with a different version of blas. I installed the atlas package (libatlas-dev libatlas-base-dev), recompiled with it, rebuilt the container, and didn't have the segfault anymore.
Still: no idea why the previous container didn't work on GCE (whereas it worked perfectly on AWS)...